# Where can I test XMLHttpRequests?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

this is about to be a super novice question.

I'm learning html/javascript/related stuff and am attempting to learn how to use XMLHttpsRequests. Most of my code (I think) is roughly correct, or at least can be easily corrected from available material out there that's easily accessible.

My confusion/question most directly relates to the `open()` method of an XHR object. What do I pass as my second parameter (url)? In the 'hands on' guides I've found people have been accessing their own websites and their own php files. The documentation however makes it sound like this second parameter can just be any url formatted as a string.

if I have my XHR object named `xmlHttp`, `xmlHttp.open("GET","http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml", true);`

is that valid? if i then `xmlHttp.send(null)` what will the server respond with? Does this vary by website? is there some way for me to specify what type of object gets sent back?

I know this is a very broad question and I'm basically asking for tutoring, but some answers regarding this low-level, pragmatic stuff would go a long way for me.

Thanks a ton

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: @SLaks I appreciate the article, and am glad to know it applies to my situation. Is there any chance you could elaborate on what this entails for my questions? As I mentioned, I'm very new to writing code for the web.

This sentence "Browsers such as Firefox 3.5 and Safari 4 use this new header to allow the cross-origin HTTP requests with XMLHttpRequest that would otherwise have been forbidden by the same-origin policy" seems applicable, but my knowledge of the underpinnings of the internet is small.

Comment: Without explicit cooperation from the remote server, you can only send AJAX requests to the website your code is running on.

Comment: @SLaks: Not exactly. You can send AJAX requests to any website, and they even will respond to you; only if SOP intervenes then you will not be able to *access* the response.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the insight. is there any way to specify how the server will respond to you (json, xml, etc.), or is that up to the server?


I know there are ways to check the type of the response after its received, but is there anyway to request a response in a certain format (lets assume that SOP didn't get in the way).

Comment: @Bergi: Still not exactly; if you set any custom headers, you need a pre-flight.

Comment: @CharlesSpinosa: You can set the `Content-Type` header in the request, but it's up to your server-side code to listen to that.

Comment: @CharlesSpinosa: No, it's totally up to the server with what it does respond. Of course, *some* APIs do offer various response formats, they might listen to URL parameters or the file extension.